# How to deploy an ASP.NET Core MVC project given its file structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

I created a web application from the Visual Studio template called **ASP.NET Core Web Application**, which has a file structure like

```
ProjectName
  Controllers
  .
  .
  wwwroot
      css
      images
      .
      . 
  .
  .
  .
```

Can I just do a **Web Deploy** to the named **Website** in IIS, just like I would a normal ASP.NET MVC site? Or does this different file structure (I'm not used to seeing wwwroot in MVC source code) mean I have to do something special?

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

Answer (score 0):

Yes can deploy the .Core Site same as ASP.NET MVC except you have to

1> Check where you have install DotNetCore.1.1.0-WindowsHosting if not please install it. 
[install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)

2> Set "No Managed Code" for .NET Framework version under application pool of your site.

Please follow above link more details